# How to get return values when I run blender script from command line?

Tags: python, scripting, blend-files, command-line, mathematics

I've got these project structure:

**data.blend:**
Contains object and used by **script.py**

**script.py:**
Does some calculation with **data.blend** and return some_value

```
import bpy
import argparse
import sys


def calculation(input_value):
    print(some_value)
    return some_value

parser = sys.argv

calculation(str(parser[-1]))
```

I want to get value of **some_value** when I launch **script.py** as cli command in **launcher.py**:

```
blender ./data.blend --background --python script.py -- input_value
```

I can do that with subprocess.check_output method in **launcher.py**.

**launcher.py**: Launch **script.py** as subprocess and get some_value from *print(some_value)* line in **script.py**.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.check_output(
    "blender ./data.blend --background --python script.py -- input_value",
    universal_newlines=True,
    shell=True
)

output_list = process.split("\n")
print("this is some_value:", output_list[0])
```

But I'm sure there's a better way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: `sys.exit(calculation(str(parser[-1])))` will cause blender to exit with `some_value` as its exit value which you can check in the CLI.

Comment: @MartyFouts thanks. That is completely ok if some_value is an integer. But if some_value is a string and I do sys.exit(some_value) in script.py then I get integer 1 from process.returncode in launcher.py. Not a string. Is there a way to get it as a string?